# Connect local network with azure

Tags: azure, network-programming, gateway

I don't know how to begin on the following. I will explain with the picture below what i want to do.

Like you so you have 2 parts. The local part and the azure part. The azure part is my part. The local network could be a customer, ....

What i went to do is running a service on the pc's and send that data to the local server/gateway. But how can i detect to what server it needs to connect. I don't install any service on the local pc's, that does the customer itself. But i don't want that he needs to do configuration. Just like they install the server/gateway part.

I will run a webservice on azure that gets information from the server/gateway on the local network. So thats no problem. On azure there are some other application that will process the messages.

Also how can you send some message back to the local network? When you say on azure ping the other local computer on the network. You should send a message to the server/gateway on your local network. But how?

So i have 2 questions(see above for more information):

- Connecting from the clients to the server/gateway
- Send some information back to the local netwerk

[image: Schema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Virtual Network, Azure Connect to create a "connection" or "hybrid cloud" between the PCs and the Azure cloud.  However, if you are talking about web based/simple messaging and the PCs have internet connectivity why not just route the messages through a secure (SSL/TLS) connection to the cloud?

For broadcasting/push-type notifications, please look at SignalR (http://signalr.net/). Microsoft is making that part of the ASP.NET platform: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-034

It has some real nice functionality like gracefully, falling back on multiple mechanisms if advanced things like WebSockets are not supported by the server/client. This is an ideal solution and super scalable, since it is server based and very light on the client.

Comment: When i have control over the pc's / server(gateway) i could use the signalr. But i don't have control over the local network. Is it then also possible to use signalr. I only want that other people need to install the server service and the pc services. And that the pc service contact the server. And the server contact the azure webservice. (hosted by myself). And i need to send information back.

Comment: I don't understand "control over PCs", because if you can't install a service that can communicate with the internet you are probably not going to be able to install VPN-like software that will tunnel outside of their firewall.  SignalR, Service Bus technologies are designed for message/client broadcasting but you will need: internet connectivity to Azure and some piece of software running on there that is configured to do so.

Comment: I can't access the PC's on the local network. Let's say that the pc's on the local network, are your pc's. So you need to install a service on your pc's and also you need to install a service on a server/gateway on your local network. The service on the server can connect to azure(becuase i know where the service is hosted). But i don't know on what machine you install your service (neither on the server as on the client pc's). I don't want that you need do some configuration. But the client pc's need to send some information to the server en vice versa.

Comment: OK..so if I can install "something" on my PCs and know the default endpoint on my cloud server/services, I can then open up a websocket connection that can send messages from the server to the clients as they "register" or ping the server and say "I am here".  That does not require a hybrid cloud and you can do broadcast messages from PCs -> server or PC -> server -> other PCs or Server -> PCs like a multi-player game or chat.  If you install a multiplayer game on a PC, do you need a hybrid cloud connection?? No.

Comment: The cloud is not yours. But it's my cloud. Only the local network is yours. :)

Comment: OK...:)  But do you understand my comments?  I am not sure if it is correct, but I still don't think you need a cloud/local network connection.

Comment: Part 1: I think i understand your comments. :)
But let me explain a little bit more.
Lets say i have a website with information about your internal PC's. I get information from you pc's on your local network. Trough the server on your local network.
You install a service on your pc's, those pc's will talk with your server on your local network. But i don't want that you need to do some configuration.

Comment: Part 2:  Everybody must be capable to install 2 services that can talk. Then the service on the server will contact my webservice on azure. And i will update my website with your information. :) So there are 2 questions. 1)How can talk between server an pc's locally 2)How can i send something back from azure to your local network

Comment: You could have the PCs locally broadcast out and "discover" the server via a specific port/protocol.  Problem with "no configuration" is that this will most likely be blocked by enterprise virus/security software .  Furthermore, your model is very similar to virus software..installed on a local PC, local PC communicates to a server (virus definitions/policies/logging etc), that local server communictes with a web based server for virus definition updates/software updates.  From all my experience, when you install virus software locally...you HAVE to configure it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your information. There are other company's that do some monitoring (system hardware, software, ....) Without any configuration.

Comment: You could do something like...local PC gets installed, pings a central server in Azure, server responds backs with further directives.  There are cloud services that automatically install entire "data centers" from zero initial config.  However, they still need to get an initial payload to tell the machines "who am I" or "where am I" or "what is my role" etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect only one or more services running on you local network and make them available publicly via azure cloud.

The most straight forward solution i found was to use the services bus. Its require nearly no modification to you business network.